# Unmute button for iOS autoplay video

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css

I know that to use the `autoplay` tag in iOS the `mute` tag also has to be used for "security reasons". I'm using something similar to `autoplay` i.e. calling `video.play()` from my JavaScript code. For this to work I also had to include the `mute` tag. I would like the user to be able to enable the sound. Ideally I want this from my own custom button. However, I can't seem to get this to work. Has anyone done this before?

**Basic Video HTML**

```
<video width="100%" id='test' class='vidInit' muted playsinline></video>
```

**Playing from JS**

```
videoCurrent = document.getElementById('test');
// ...
videoCurrent.play();
```

**Unmute Button** - doesn't work :(

```
let unmute = document.createElement('img');
unmute.style = 'background-color: blue; position: absolute; display: block; left: 100px; top: 100px; width: 100px; height: 100px;';
unmute.onclick = function() {
    video.muted = false;
    console.log('UNMUTE');
}
navbar.appendChild(unmute);
```

Comment: is it because you do not use button but image?

Comment: I don't think so, the `console.log('UNMUTE');` seems to get called

Comment: Where have you declared video variable on which you are trying to call muted = 'false'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable referencing the video element is called `videoCurrent`, but in the click event handler you're trying to use a variable simply called `video`, which is undefined. Here's a working example showing that it is indeed working when you use the correct reference. I also changed the line doing the muting to

```
videoCurrent.muted = !videoCurrent.muted;
```

in order to be able to toggle the mute/unmute state for the sake of this demonstration.

By the way, you should have seen an error message explaining the issue in the console, right before the `"UNMUTE"` was logged.

```js
var videoCurrent = document.getElementById('test');
var navbar = document.querySelector('nav');
videoCurrent.play();

let unmute = document.createElement('img');
unmute.style = 'background-color: blue; position: absolute; display: block; left: 100px; top: 100px; width: 100px; height: 100px;';
unmute.onclick = function() {
  videoCurrent.muted = !videoCurrent.muted;
  console.log('UNMUTE');
}
navbar.appendChild(unmute);
```

```html
<nav></nav>
<video width="100%" id='test' class='vidInit' src='http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4' muted playsinline></video>
```